# Xperia S Responsive Design

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport, sony

I cannot make a website responsive on Xperia S.

Because of command line :

> meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"

Everything is zoomed and moved to the left, when on other mobiles it looks good. Screenshot :

http://www.domweselnysenden.pl/screenshot.png

The website I am testing.

http://domweselnysenden.pl

Comment: Remove the tag you posted in your question or change the values appropriately.

Comment: The problem is, when I am doing it, Xperia works well, be the others, no at all.